# POST request is always empty

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest

I have a function which sends a POST request to my node.js server, but the headers, params, cookies and everything is empty. I've checked my browser console and it was sent, there's just nothing in it. Can anyone help my identify the problem? (`email` and `pass` isn't empty, either.)

```
function sendPostRequest() {
    const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    const pass = document.getElementById('pass').value;
    var params = 'email=' + email + "&pass=" + pass;
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000", true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.send(params);
}
```

Comment: what is the status in your network explorer?

Comment: @MThiele if you meant the Status Code, there's none.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps to fix the error

1. Check network tab in browser developer console whether it's passing the data or not if not the problem is in front end.
2. If that is true, then check backend and print the request body if there it's not coming then it's backend